# Bash: Split a string by delimiter ignoring spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have string like

```
name1::1.1.1.1::ps -ax
```

I want to split the string based on delimiter `::` using bash scripting.

The desired output should be an array of 3 elements

```
("name1" "1.1.1.1" "ps -ax")
```

without double quotes

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Comment: One difference: those links, which both point to the same question, apply to the use of a single character as a delimiter.  The question here uses two-characters for the delimiter.

Comment: Please clarify whether the data can contain _single_ `:`s, for example `ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there are no `:`s in the array data, use `bash` pattern substitution to squeeze the `::` to `:` while assigning the string to `$array`, then show the whole array, then just element *#2*:

```
a="name1::1.1.1.1::ps -ax"
IFS=: array=(${a//::/:}) ; echo ${array[@]} ; echo "${array[2]}"
```

Output:

```
name1 1.1.1.1 ps -ax
ps -ax
```

---

But what if there are `:`s in the array data?  Specifically in the third field, (the command), and *only* in that field.  Use `read` with dummy variables to absorb the extra `::` separators:

```
a="name1::1.1.1.1::parallel echo ::: 1 2 3 ::: a b"
IFS=: read x a y b z <<< "$a"; array=("$x" "$y" "$z"); printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

Output:

```
name1
1.1.1.1
parallel echo ::: 1 2 3 ::: a b
```

Comment: But then the values cannot contain any single colons, which I imagine was the reason the OP chose double colons in the first place.  You could replace double colons with something unlikely like `$'\xff'` though. `IFS=$'\xff' array=(${a//::/$'\xff'})`

Comment: @tripleee, Instead of imagining the OP's reason, let's [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333288/bash-split-a-string-by-delimiter-ignoring-spaces/46334343?noredirect=1#comment79638591_46333288).  Also the `\xff` still wouldn't work correctly if  `${array[2]}` were a command like `parallel --link diff {1} {2} :::: manifest1 checklist1`.

Comment: If the commands contain double colons then obviously double colons are not a good separator to use in this context in the first place.

Comment: @tripleee, Agreed.  Either method makes assumptions about what's *not* in the data, and may hit corner cases.  A more general fix would be if the data format instead used counted strings, (say a border delimiter for human readability, the number of chars to the *next* delimiter or linefeed, then the item data), *e.g.* `:7:name1:9:1.1.1.1:8:ps -ax`.

Comment: That's not a particularly good scheme. Use a standard data format with well-defined semantics and escaping mechanisms like JSON if you have complex requirements.

Comment: @tripleee,  I'd be interested to see a simple example of a data item (given the OP's type of data) that a counted string wouldn't handle.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, just that if your requirements are nontrivial,  I'd move to a standardized solution instead of rolliing my own.

Answer (score 1):

The only safe possibility is use a loop:

```
a='name1::1.1.1.1::ps -ax'
array=()

a+=:: # artificially append the separator
while [[ $a ]]; do
    array+=( "${a%%::*}" )
    a=${a#*::}
done
```

This will work with any symbol in `a` (spaces, glob characters, newlines, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0                                                                            
string="name1::1.1.1.1::ps -ax"                                                
echo "$string" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="::";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1;print $0}'>tempFile            
while read line;                                                               
do                                                                             
  arr["$i"]="$line"                                                                  
  i=$(expr $i + 1)                                                              
done<tempFile                                                                  
echo "${arr[@]}"                                                                
echo "${arr[0]}"                                                                
echo "${arr[1]}"                                                                
echo "${arr[2]}"
```

Output:

```
sh-4.4$ ./script1.sh
name1 1.1.1.1 ps -ax
name1
1.1.1.1
ps -ax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "name1::1.1.1.1::ps -ax" | awk -F"::" '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

Comment: This doesn't particularly help, you might as well `echo "${value//::/ }"`.  The task is to get the individual members parsed into a Bash array.